# Graph theory software?

Tags: graph-theory, math-software

Is there any software that for drawing graphs (edges and nodes) that gives detailed maths data such as degree of each node, density of the graph and that can help with shortest path problem and with algorithms such as Dijkstra ?

Thanks!

Comment: Community wiki?

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13841/online-tool-for-making-graphs-vertices-and-edges/13843#13843)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are comfortable using Python, I've found [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/) to be quite useful for generating graphs and doing the types of calculations you mention.

Answer (score 14):

[graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is quite good and opensource. I used my own software to create dot- files and let graphviz interpret them. I have used it on Linux, but there seems to exist a windows-port as well.

Answer (score 9):

[Gephi](https://gephi.org/) is a respectable package for network analysis.  It can calculate the usual network measures, apply various filters, can draw graphs in various ways, and so on.

Here's an example of a network drawn by Gephi:

[image: Example Gephi drawing]

Answer (score 7):

Try [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/) ! It does all this and much more.

Nathann

Comment: Yes, Sage is great!

Answer (score 6):

Have you heard of [CmapTools](http://cmap.ihmc.us/)? It's dedicated for concept maps, but if you don't mind having keywords on every arc, you could give it a try.
[image: CmapTools in action. Imagine you leave the arc keywords blank...]

Answer (score 4):

A very quick trip to Google showed me [Graph Magic](http://www.graph-magics.com/) (an actual software) and [graphdrawing](http://graphdrawing.org/) (a group concerned with graph software, and that appears to have high standards and experience from their site), both of which look to be excellent and exactly what you ask.

For what it's worth, when I Felt Lucky, I went [here](http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Math/Combinatorics/Software/Graph_Drawing/).

Comment: Please explain the downvote - perhaps you didn't like the fact that I emphasized how easy it was to get this information from google. But it's accurate, and graph magic does look very good.

Answer (score 4):

I also found Cytoscape quite interesting. (also Mathematica from Wolfram)

Comment: I also found NodeBox with Graph very interesting (http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph#loading_the_library)

Answer (score 3):

try Graph Tea
http://www.graphtheorysoftware.com/
this is more easier way to implement graph algorithms

Comment: While this seems to be a fairly new (2014) open source package, Readers would likely benefit from an illustration or personal experience with the software.  Given the passage of time since the Question was asked, brief answers are not especially desired.

Answer (score 2):

[igraph](https://igraph.org/) is a free and open source package for graph theory and network analysis. It can be programmed in [C](https://igraph.org/c/), [R](https://igraph.org/r/), [Python](https://igraph.org/python/) and [Mathematica](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM). It supports all pieces of functionality you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [NS2](http://isi.edu/nsnam/ns/) which is a network simulator.  It will not give you proofs but can give you a simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found [GraphTea](http://www.graphtheorysoftware.com/) (but at first glance I cannot see how to make it work for weighted graphs).

Answer (score 1):

http://graphonline.ru/en/

This one help draw graph with vertex & edge, support weight / direction.

It also support to export as image or matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it personally, but [Petersen](http://www.mathcove.net/petersen/lessons/intro?les=0) is supposed to be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Gephi at http://gephi.org . It is an open source graph visualization system