# How to check if a graph is biplanar (thickness =2)?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Given a graph G how does one check if it can be decomposed into 2 planar graphs other than enumeration.

Note: my given graph has 52 edges and 11 nodes.

[image]

Quick edit: the graph has an edge from  4 to 1*

Comment: Maybe there is a [graph theory software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58973/graph-theory-software) which can do this. Or, if you provide us the graph, maybe someone would be able to check whether its thickness is two by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma:

> The thickness of $K_n$ is $\lfloor\frac{n+7}{6}\rfloor$ when $n\neq 9,10$ and for cases $n=9,10$ it is $3$.

So if there exists a $K_a$ with $a\geq 9$ in your graph (lets call it $G$), that subgraph has a thickness of at least $3$, so $G$ has a thickness of al least $3$

So for your graph to have a thickness of $2$, it must not have any $K_9$s as subgraphs. Using [Turan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem), the maximum number of edges of a graph with $11$ vertices which is $K_9-$free is $52$ and if this bound is touched by some graph, it is the [Turan graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) $T(11,8)$.

Thus, your graph **does not** have a thickness of $2$ if it is not the Turan graph. If your graph is the Turan graph $T(11,8)$, then observe that it doesnt actually have $52$ edges so again, there is a $K_9$, so your graph has a thickness of at least $3$.

So you graph has a thickness $\geq 3$.

Some closing remarks:

> It is NP-hard to compute the thickness of a given graph, and NP-complete to test whether the thickness is at most two.

It is pretty hard to just test the thickness of a graph, as cited above from Wikipedia, especially if you do not have the graph and only the number of vertices and edges are given.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the lemma?

Comment: Hello there. There are actually many more lemmas reagrding thickness. See this: https://domino.mpi-inf.mpg.de/internet/reports.nsf/efc044f1568a0058c125642e0064c817/9097519627562713c125630a0047835e/$FILE/MPI-I-96-1-009.pdf

Comment: Why are you saying that the Turán graph doesn't actually have $52$ edges? Start with $K_{11}$, which has $55$ edges. Then delete $3$ independent edges $v_1w_1, v_2w_2, v_3w_3$ to get $52$. A clique in the resulting graph can only have one of $\{v_1, w_1\}$, only one of $\{v_2, w_2\}$, and only one of $\{v_3, w_3\}$, so it can have at most $11-3=8$ edges, and we have a $52$-edge graph which is $K_9$-free.