# how can we make 11 non-isomorphic graphs on 4-vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

How can we draw all the non-isomorphic graphs on $4$ vertices ? But it is mentioned that $ 11 $ graphs are possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just mentioning a couple of links you might find useful to answer similar questions.

1. [List of Small Graphs](http://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html)
2. [Related Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13841/online-tool-for-making-graphs-vertices-and-edges)

Answer (score 2):

Start by drawing the 4 vertices. Then draw all the possible graphs with 0 edges (there is only one). Next, draw all the possible graphs with 1 edge (again, there is only one). Continue until you draw the complete graph on 4 vertices. You should end up with 11 graphs.

Comment: The part you describe as "Continue" is before enough information is available to establish the pattern which needs to be continued! It's like saying of the primes, start at 1, go to 2 and then so on!

Comment: We are ordering the graphs by the number of edges. First we draw all graphs with 0 edges, then 1, 2, $\ldots$, until we've made a complete graph (which has the maximal number of edges).

Answer (score 2):

Label the vertices $1,2,3,4$.

There are $11$ non-Isomorphic graphs.

1. With $0$ edges only $1$ graph
2. with $1$ edges only $1$ graph: e.g $(1,2)$ from $1$ to $2$
3. With $2$ edges $2$ graphs: e.g $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ or $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$
4. With $3$ edges $3$ graphs: e.g $(1,2),(2,4)$ and $(2,3)$ or $(1,2),(2,3)$ and $(1,3)$ or $(1,2),(2,3)$ and $(3,4)$
5. with $4$ edges $2$ graphs: e.g $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)$ and $(1,4)$ or $(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)$ and $(2,4)$
6. With $5$ edges only $1$ graph: $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,4)$ and $(1,3)$
7. With $6$ edges only $1$ graph: $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,4),(1,3)$ and $(2,4)$

All those non-isomorphic graphs are $1+1+2+3+2+1+1=11$

Comment: Thanks Victor Tomno! Your answer helped me correct my illustration - specifically, I referred to the number of simple graphs with 4 vertices with n edges from your post to correct my https://twitter.com/c010011012/status/1380804215900045313 while figuring out my self what those graphs looked like

Answer (score 0):

How many non-isomorphic graphs can you draw with $4$ vertices and $0$ edges? How many with $1$ edge? $2$? $\dots$

Comment: with 4 vertices all graphs drawn are isomorphic if the no. of edges are 0,1,2.

Comment: @mahavir This is not true with 4 vertices and 2 edges.